# How to connect a particular user and create database using PostgreSQL and ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I need to create a database inside using a particular username and import the `.sql file` using PostgreSQL and Ubuntu. I have created one user using the below command.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser user1 -s
```

I need command to create one database `spesh`  under this particular owner and import the `spesh.sql` into it.

Comment: You're creating a new database for each user?  That can't possibly scale to lots of users.  Wouldn't a better design be a central repository with a USER table?

Comment: @duffymo : i needed to create it under that particular owner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create db spesh with owner user1

```
sudo -u postgres createdb "spesh" -O user1
```

import sql dump into spesh database

```
sudo -u postgres psql spesh < 'file_path.sql'
```